# Need help setting up phpLiteAdmin

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to set up phpLiteAdmin with no knowledge of PHP, but I'm stuck. My Apache/PHP install is working (I already run myWebSQL), and I deployed the phpLiteAdmin with the sqlite file next to it, which then lets me use the default config (no change to the password yet).

However, after logging in, I'm only getting this screen with no error:
[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

R.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be using PHP 7.

If your web server `error.log` has the error:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_strlen()

Then the solution is straightforward.

To install the function:

```
sudo apt-get install phpX.X-mbstring
```

Where X.X is your version of PHP.

Restart your web server.

It should then work.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't on their installation web page. It's not that simple an issue to search for (as in: good search terms to describe what is happening), so I can only imagine others have spent quite a while searching for it. I'll send them an email.